# RIS: Risetup flat image only shows up on multiprocessor machines

Tags: windows-server-2003, pxe-boot

I've got a RIsetup image that should, theoretically, show up on all pxe compatable clients. Right now it only shows up on machines with multiple processors.

Answer (score 2):

Your image was set up on a computer with multiprocessors, I would guess.  The HAL then would be wrong for any machine without more than one processor .  (refer to this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309283) and this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289638)).  You should regenerate the image using an initial computer with the correct HAL.

Another option is to use a sysprep solution.  Changing HALs with a sysprep image is easier, described in this [blog](http://blog.case.edu/djc6/2005/09/22/imaging_machines_using_different_hals_wsysprep), and Microsoft's sysprep documents are in this [support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577).

Comment: Yes, that would be the solution, if this was a riprep image. This is a flat image, so basically it's a copy of the xp cd booted over the network. The CD works on both types of machines, ris only works on multiprocessor.